# How to set object to nullptr after self deletion

Tags: c++, qt

I have a dialog window with a class of QDialog. 
I declare it in the header files with:

```
MyDialogClass myDialogWindow = nullptr;
```

and create the window on runtime somewhere with

```
myDialogWindow = new MyDialogClass(this);
```

It is also delf destroying, because of it's attributes:

```
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
```

Does anyone now how can I set the myDialogWindow pointer to nullptr after the self deletion without connection signals?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To do that you need to know **when** your dialog was destroyed. You cannot know that without handling events or signals unless you delete that dialog explicitly.

Comment: The idea of the "delete on close" is that you don't keep the pointers to the object ....

Comment: The short answer is "you can't".   An object can't generally access all the pointers pointing at itself and assign them to null in standard C++.  A couple of pointer assignments like `p = &object;  p1 = p;` gives `object` no information whatsoever about the variables `p` or `p1`.   That's *why* qt has connection signals, and similar libraries have similar facilities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't possible without some signal or event logic. The object does not own the pointer, the pointer is pointing at the object.

However you can use a QPointer which wraps the signal handling and nulling for you.

```
QPointer<MyDialogClass> myDialogWindow;
myDialogWindow = new MyDialogClass(this);
myDialogWindow->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

// some time later, check dialog has not been closed
if( ! myDialogWindow.isNull() )
{
    // do something with dialog
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can catch when the object is destroyed, and erase the pointer.

```
connect(myDialogWindow, &QObject::destroyed, [&myDialogWindow](){ myDialogWindow = nullptr;});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in general. Any `T` cannot know whether it is being used as `T` or `T&` or `T*`, and you can't automatically change all relevant `T*` to `nullptr` from inside `T` (because it doesn't know about them).

You need some other way to be informed that your `MyDialogClass` instance was destroyed - a signal for example.